What are these large elevated regions in Northern Canada?
Complete newbie to any earth sciences here. Please tell me if this is the wrong stack exchange website
I was browsing around on google earth (as one does), and I noticed these "discoloured" regions in upper Canada.
I checked on a topographical map, and saw that they were higher up than the land surrounding them too.
On Google Earth:


On topographical map:


What are these land forms, and what could have created them?
Note: For anyone looking for a good online topographical map, go here, click the layers icon on the top bar, and enable 'elevation tinted hillshade'.

You're looking at a dissected tableland, the relatively flat upper surfaces are an old flattened (by erosion and/or sediment deposition) ground surface. Given that the valleys cutting through appear to be quite steep sided and flat bottomed, I would guess that the primary erosive force is late stage glacial action towards the end of the last ice age. The original plateau was probably flattened out by the action of earlier ice sheets at a time closer to the last glacial maximum.
